# Understanding AJAX php script for clue game practice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to understand the relationship between a PHP script I'd like to run to keep track of progress and the front end work that has taken place. Its 2 clues in a game practice. Once the clue is inputted correctly everything occurs as below and I want to add a script that sends to MYSQL.

I'm working on the script now, but I'm trying to figure out at what point I'd introduce this. Is there anything I'd need within my PHP to distinguish it as AJAX. As in to run it in the background? Do I just "include" it as I would part of another larger PHP script?

The script in my mind will send a 1 if correct or 0 if still wrong. This way I can easily determine without having to deal with clues. The clues are irrelevant in my thinking, but what is your opinion on this?

```
// =====clue 1====================////////////////// clue 1 **************
//**********************************========================
$(document).on('click', '.btn-clue', function(){ 
    if($i!=1){
       $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "includes/post_clue_progress",
                  data: { clueTwo: "1", usernameClue: "<?php echo $manager; ?>" }
                })
              .done(function( msg ) {
                // msg is any data that is echoed in the php script or output to screen is some way
                $("#clueWrongTwo").hide();
                $("#mySecondDivClueTwo").remove();
                $("#clueTwo").remove();
                $("#clue2Input").remove();
                $two.show();
                $("#clueTwoInputCorrect").slideDown('slow').show();
                $i++;
              });   
        } else {
            $("#mySecondDiv").remove();
            var mySecondDiv = $('<div id="mySecondDiv"><img src="images/check-x-mark.png" /></div>').show('slow');
            $('#clueWrongOne').append(mySecondDiv);
        }
    }
});
// =====clue 2====================////////////////// clue 2*********=========
$(document).on('click', '.btn-clueTwo', function(){ 
    if($i!=1){
        //checking if textbox has desired value (1 in this case),
        //in your application you would be passing the textbox value to 
        //ajax here and making the check at server side
        var $two = $('#twoClueShow');
        var x = $("#clueTwoInput").find('input[type=text]').val();
        if(x == 'C' || x == 'CS') {
            // if answer correct you should load data from ajax 
                    // and append it to a container

            $("#clueWrongTwo").hide();
            $("#mySecondDivClueTwo").remove();
            $("#clueTwo").remove();
            $("#clue2Input").remove();
            $two.show();
            $("#clueTwoInputCorrect").slideDown('slow').show();
            $i++;
        } else {
        $("#mySecondDivClueTwo").remove();
        var mySecondDivClueTwo = $('<div id="mySecondDivClueTwo"><img src="images/check-x-mark.png" /></div>') .show('slow');
            $('#clueWrongTwo').append(mySecondDivClueTwo);
        }
    }
});
```

Above is where I've been able to get. Now here is where I'm getting confused. I now want to send to the database that the answer has been answered correctly through AJAX, correct? Would I just include_once my php script in the commented area.

I was thinking of creating a script that filled a 1 if correct and 0 if not correct to make life easier. Let this do the work as I don't need to reintroduce the inputs or re use. This way once the page has reloaded I could simply not output the inputs again and use this info to determine what is displayed and where they are at in the clue game. Basically saving progress.

Is there something specific to use when building my normal PHP. I guess that and where to "include" it is where I'm confused.

MY button for reference

```
<div id="clueOneInput">
    <input type="text" id="clue1" class="clue-text form-control" placeholder="Enter Clue 1 here and check"/>
</div>
<input type="button" id="clue1Input"class="btn btn-primary btn-clue" value="Check">
```

Update :

```
// =====clue 1====================////////////////// clue 1**********************************************************************========================
$(document).on('click', '.btn-clue', function(){ 
    if($i!=1){
        //checking if textbox has desired value (1 in this case),
        //in your application you would be passing the textbox value to ajax here and making the check at server side
        var $one = $('#oneClueShow');
        var x = $("#clueOneInput").find('input[type=text]').val();
        if(x == 'd' || x == 'dr')

        {
            //if answer correct you should load data from ajax and append it to a container
            $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "includes/post_clue_progress",
                      data: { clueOne: "1", usernameClue: "<?php echo $manager; ?>" }
                    })
                  .done(function( msg ) {
                    // msg is any data that is echoed in the php script or output to screen is some way
                    $("#clueWrongOne").hide();
                    $("#mySecondDiv").remove();
                    $("#clueOne").remove();
                    $("#clue1Input").remove();
                    $one.show();
                    $("#clueOneInputCorrect").slideDown('slow').show();
                    $i++;
                  });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#mySecondDiv").remove();
            var mySecondDiv = $('<div id="mySecondDiv"><img src="images/check-x-mark.png" /></div>').show('slow');
            $('#clueWrongOne').append(mySecondDiv);
        }
    }
});
// =====clue 2====================////////////////// clue 2**********************************************************************========================
$(document).on('click', '.btn-clueTwo', function(){ 
    if($i!=1){
        var $two = $('#twoClueShow');
        var x = $("#clueTwoInput").find('input[type=text]').val();
        if(x == 'CS' || x == 'CSU')
        {
            $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "includes/post_clue_progress",
                      data: { clueTwo: "1", usernameClue: "<?php echo $manager; ?>" }
                    })
                  .done(function( msg ) {
                    // msg is any data that is echoed in the php script or output to screen is some way
                    $("#clueWrongTwo").hide();
                    $("#mySecondDivClueTwo").remove();
                    $("#clueTwo").remove();
                    $("#clue2Input").remove();
                    $two.show();
                    $("#clueTwoInputCorrect").slideDown('slow').show();
                    $i++;
                  });   
        }
        else
        {
            $("#mySecondDivClueTwo").remove();
            var mySecondDivClueTwo=$('<div id="mySecondDivClueTwo"><img src="images/check-x-mark.png" /></div>').show('slow');
            $('#clueWrongTwo').append(mySecondDivClueTwo);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You do not need to define a php script as AJAX-able. All it is, is another script that you are calling via a JQuery AJAX call.  You define the URL as the path to your exposed script and either post/get your data to it.  Also it is a good idea to put some authentication in there so people cannot just hit your ajax script whenever it wants to.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still confused, but I think we're on the same page. JQuery AJAX call is I believe what I'm trying to understand. So in PHP if I wanted to call a script I would place something like this `include_once "includes/test.php";` or `include "includes/test.php";` Is this something that occurs here or is it done in another way?

Comment: So before `$("#clueWrongOne").hide();` I would include and send to the database the info. This is what you mean by "All it is, is another script that you're calling"?

Comment: posted an answer to give an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Jquery

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "yourScriptToUpdateDB.php",
  data: { clue: "Wrong", user: "JoeBob" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    // msg is any data that is echoed in the php script or output to screen is some way
    $("#clueWrongOne").hide();
  });
```

Comment: I've used your reference to come up with the above update. I'm not getting any errors and can't seem to get any error to pop up. Can you take a look and let me know if I'm missing something elementary or if I'm way off. Right now nothing is being posted to the database. Normally I'd var dump, but if it's being run off page through the script is there another way to do this?

Comment: Also! your $(document).on('click'.... call is bad form. It wont give you errors but you are parsing your entire DOM looking for all objects with the class 'btn-clickTwo'. It is a better idea if you can directly target things because it saves search time.

Comment: Whoops sorry about that. Updated now. Does the $(document) have anything to do with not being able to do the same with other clue variables after the first has been run?

Comment: Scratch the second half of that last comment. I had an error in my code preventing others from occuring. 

Can you expand a bit on what you meany by the $(document).on('click'.....?

Comment: Your code $(document).on('click', '.btn-clueTwo', function(){ ... } That is going to traverse the entire DOM of the webpage. With an ID selector '#id_of_element' you can directly target and element and get the data faster.  Its not the worst way to do what you are trying to do but you can optimise (noticeable with larger doms and lots of elements classed the same)

Comment: I believe I've been able to get it. Right now I'm working on intertwining the php within this. This is something I should be good to go with. Thanks for your help. The hard way though. I tried to merge everything in a clever way so I didn't have to re-write each clue script, but for now I want to get it running. Then I'll try and learn and break it down in a better way. What I really didn't understand was the the data was being used as php post. I didn't know that was a connection or rather how to establish that connection.